# Directly integrable, separable and linear?

Tags: calculus

I have an assignment that asks whether an ODE is directly integrable, separable and/or linear. This is a modified version of the given question:

> $\frac{da}{db} = |a|,a(0) = 0$

$$-------------$$

Edit:

Direct integration gives: $|a|\cdot b +c$, $\therefore$ $c= 0$

Is separable?
$$\frac{1}{|a|}\cdot da = 1\cdot db$$
$$\ln a + c \text{ Note this is undefined(ln0)}$$

$$-------------$$
Now, my logic:

$ |a| = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       a & : a\geq0\\
       -a & : a\lt0
     \end{array}
   \right.$

$a(0) = 0$, so $a'(0) = 0$, and hence $\frac{da}{db} = a$, so it is therefore directly integrable: $a = ab+c$ $\rightarrow a = \frac{c}{1-b}$

It is seperable as $\frac{da}{|a|} = 1\cdot db$, noting the previous observation on $|a|$, we have $a = C\cdot e^b$, where $C$ is constant $e^c$.

These are not equal(?) so one or both of my assumptions don't work. Furthermore, it is linear if my assumption holds($|a| = a$)

Apparently it is not linear, and I am wondering if this is in regards to the fact it is $|a| = \sqrt{a^2}$?

I believe that it may not be directly integrable if you consider the fact that it should actually have two integrals before considering the initial condition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, note this is homework, so it would be appreciated if you didn't just give me the answer!

Comment: It is apparently non-linear. But I am unsure of whether it is actually separable and/or directly integrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $a(0)=0$, the first answer force $c=0$ which yields only the constant function. In the second case, we see again that the only way to make $a(0)=0$ is to have $C=0$, which is impossible since $C=e^c$.

I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this, but this is a first order, non-linear differential equation according to Wolfram though.

Comment: I think it should be linear though. Generally linear first order ODEs take the form $\frac{da}{db} = q(b) - p(b)a$, where we currently have $q(b) = 0, p(b) = -1$.

Comment: Which I suppose means my assumption for $|a| = a$ is wrong.

Comment: Oh, yes. $|a|=a$ is simply false. Why did you conjecture that.

Comment: Since we know $a(0) = 0$, we know $a'(0) = 0$, so $\frac{da}{db} = |a|$ where $\frac{da}{db} = 0$, since $|a| = a$ when $a \geq 0$, $|a| = a$.

Comment: Compare with $\frac{da}{db}=b^2$. It's quite possible for $a(b)<0,\forall b<0$

Your first comment is wrong. We have $p(b)=\frac{|b|}{b}$, which is not a polynomial.